# Jenkins - view results in web browser

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins job runs many tests that create log files. In case of failure, I want to look at the log of the failed test. I'd rather use Jenkins web-server to do it, even have a link in the email it sends me.

Is there any plugin that can do it? Or maybe another way?

Answer (score 0):

You provide few details in your question, so it is impossible to give specific advice. In a general level: this is already possible. When your test framework creates JUnit XML files with test results, the test output can be included between the `<failure>` and `</failure>` tags. Usually test frameworks should take care of this automatically, so you are probably not using a test framework and are manually generating the XML files containing test results?

I recommend you adopt some test framework. It is usually well worth the effort.

Comment: I'm using TestNG. It tells me which tests failed, but nothing else.